# how to convert date to firebase timestamp format in android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

How to convert date into firebase timestamp format in android

My date is - 01-01-2021
Result Format I need is - January 01, 2021 at 3:37:59 PM UTC+5:30(firebase timestamp format)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to only format that date or do you want to set a Firestore Timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

> **Date**: Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as
> "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

`import java.util.Date`

Simply use `Date()` as `val date = Date()` (firebase timestamp format)

[image]

while fetching data from firebase use below code

```kotlin
val date = getReadableDateTime(document.getDate("timestamp")) // timpestamp is the key inside your document


private fun getReadableDateTime(date: Date): String {
        return SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy - hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(date)
    }
```